# What is a store detective allowed to do?

Tags: criminal-law, theft, austria

A couple of days ago I came into contact with a store detective after a quite expensive shopping trip. The shoplifting gate-thingy went off (there's more to it but no need to drag it out) and when I was already outside, the store detective approached me, eventually even grabbed me and tried to rip my shopping bag off my shoulder. I had to call for help and the guy only let go when he saw other people approaching to help me.

He was later joined by a second "detective" and they both refused to let me leave (cornered me in front of a different store) - they didn't even want to let me use the toilet. Eventually the police showed up, checked my bag (the second "detective" looked at the receipt to check) and proved that I indeed hadn't stolen anything, as I'd said at least 10 times.

I can't find any information about Austria, so I hope that someone here'll be able to help me: What is a store detective legally allowed to do?

1. Do I have to answer any questions (e.g. if I bought anything at that store)?
2. Do I have to show them a receipt?
3. Are they allowed to check my backpack/shopping bag/... without my permission?
4. Are they allowed to grab someone without consent?
5. Are they allowed to take away a bag forcefully?
6. Are they allowed to follow me outside the shop?
7. When the police show up, does any of that change or are only they allowed to check my bag,...?

So basically: What can I do now? I'm not physically hurt but I'm completely over the place since then - not sleeping well, getting kind of shaky when I think about this (and incredibly angry)?

Answer (score 5):

Here is what the [Austrian law](https://www.oesterreich.gv.at/themen/dokumente_und_recht/strafrecht/5/Seite.2460402.html) says in this case (Google translation):

> Bag control in the supermarket: There is no obligation to have your
> bag checked by supermarket staff or security guards. If there is a
> reasonable suspicion, the supermarket staff can ask a suspect to wait
> for the police to arrive. The police can then check the bag.

In this [Austrian newspaper article (in German)](https://www.wienerzeitung.at/nachrichten/wirtschaft/oesterreich/88249-Wie-weit-darf-der-Kaufhausdetektiv-eigentlich-gehen.html) they say about this topic

> If a person is injured during the arrest because of a low value item
> or if an expensive item is damaged, the detective might be liable for it.

As long as they don't start searching your bags, they are allowed to hold on to you till police arrives. I would complain to the shop owner about the detectives and their behavior via mail, this is probably the most efficient thing what one can do.

Answer (score 1):

The laws you are looking for is the so-called "Jedermannsrecht".

Essentially: Anyone, not just a store detective, does have the legal right to stop you and keep you **until the police arrives**, if and only if, they have witnessed you committing a crime.

Legally speaking, a store detective is just a random person, the same as any shopper or store employee. He has no special rights except maybe a broader range of "Hausrecht" (property right) granted to him to excercise in the name of the property owner. For example, he may be authorised to trespass you (i.e. tell you not to enter the property again).

So the answers are:

1. no
2. no
3. no
4. yes, as required to keep you from escaping and only until the police arrive
5. no
6. yes (the law says if they witnessed a crime, they can follow you in their attempt to hold you for the police)
7. yes, as soon as police show up, they need to stop following and holding you and hand you over to the police

Comment: But in this case, nobody witnessed a crime because _there was no crime._  This is a case of mere suspicion.  What does the law say about _Jedermannsrecht_ in such cases?  Is there some threshold of reasonable suspicion that triggers it?  If so, where is that threshold?  Can anyone detain someone who sets off the shoplifting alarm?  Is training in the efficacy of the alarm and the store's use of merchandise tags relevant?

Comment: @phoog that's different questions and not easy. In general, the law says "auf frischer Tat ertappt" and in general a crime must actually have happened, suspicion of a crime is not enough. But things get a bit muddy there, and much is a case-by-case issue ("Verhältnismäßigkeit", etc.)

Comment: But it is not a different question, because here there is no crime.  The security guard observed the alarm sounding when someone left the store.  This suggests that a crime may have occurred, but I would bet that statistics on shoplifting alarms would show that a false alarm is more likely.  More importantly, on the facts given in the question, it _was_ a false alarm.  The most prominent crime in the question is perhaps the assault by the guard on the customer.

Comment: @phoog yes, false alarms in these systems are common. I am not aware of any cases that resolve this question, so it would be pure speculation to decide what exactly a shop detective may or may not do based on just the alarm.